# Having trouble with matching a string with escaped quotes using Regular Expressions in Java

Tags: java, regex, matching

I saw similar questions to mine but I still can't find the problem. If you find a similar question, I would appreciate it if you could send me the link in the comments.

I am trying to match content of a text file for escaped double quotes (`\"`) and single quotes (`\'`). The reason for this is that I have to extract everything in quotes and paste it into another text file. This is what my text file (that needs to be compared) looks like:

```
<pre>
    string0 = "Report:   \n";
    string1 = "File1 Name: \"Inferno\" \tFile2 Name: \"Gollum\"";
    string2 = "Similarities: \'parameter1\' \t \'parameter3\' \t \'parameter4\'";
    string3 = "Differences: \'parameter2\'";
</pre>
```

So I need a regular expression that will work in Java (Java's Pattern class) that can match these escape single and double quote characters. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Let me know if further explanation is required.

Comment: What part of this text you want to match?

Comment: @anubhava I wanted to match every `string#` variable

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class QuotesPattern {

    static Pattern DOUBLE_QUOTES = Pattern.compile("\\\"(.+?)\\\"");
    static Pattern SINGLE_QUOTES = Pattern.compile("\\\'(.+?)\\\'");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String string0 = "Report:   \n";
        String string1 = "File1 Name: \"Inferno\" \tFile2 Name: \"Gollum\"";
        String string2 = "Similarities: \'parameter1\' \t \'parameter3\' \t \'parameter4\'";
        String string3 = "Differences: \'parameter2\'";

        printValues(string0);
        printValues(string1);
        printValues(string2);
        printValues(string3);
    }

    private static void printValues(String string) {
        Matcher doubleQuotesMather = DOUBLE_QUOTES.matcher(string);
        while(doubleQuotesMather.find()) {
            System.out.println(doubleQuotesMather.group(1));
        }

        Matcher singleQuotesMatcher = SINGLE_QUOTES.matcher(string);
        while(singleQuotesMatcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(singleQuotesMatcher.group(1));
        }
    }

}
```

The idea here is both double quotes(") and slash() could be escaped with slash(). So if you want to escape and match \" you could place a slash() before each character to make \\". Similarly for \' it becomes \\'. If you want to combine both to one regex you could use pipe(|) operator.

Comment: The accumulation of backslashes in front of `"` is useless; a single backslash is sufficent in Pattern DOUBLE_QUOTES: `"\"(.+?)\""`. Likewise, you can omit *all* backslashes in Pattern SINGLE_QUOTES: `"'(.+?)'"`. Try it!

Answer (score 0):

To match a quote:

```
Pattern,compile( "\"" );
```

To match an apostrophe:

```
Pattern.compile( "'" );
```

The backslash-escaping of an apostrophe is pointless: it'll remain a simple apostrophe.

Perhaps a little excursion on quoting in Java, If you have the text: `He said, "Let's go!"`, its Java representation as a literal is

```
"He said, \"Let's go!\""
```

If this character sequence is stored in a String object, you can match the quotes and the apostrophe using the regular expression given above. The String does not contain a backslash character.

Answer (score -1):

Most of your cases could be matched with:

```
 "((\\\".*?\\\")|(\\\'.*?\\\'))"
```

which says to match \" any text, then \". The reluctant qualifier .*? will stop before the next escaped quote. And it will match single or double quotes.

Just use find, then group(1) to get the text (including escapes and quotes).

What it wouldn't correctly match is one escaped quoted string (single quotes) inside another escaped quoted string (double quotes). But perhaps that's not a necessary case for you.

Comment: Downvoted due to the pointless accumulation of backslashes. See comments elsewhere.

Comment: @laune Read the OP post again - he is specifically looking to capture entries that include the backslash. The examples include quotes without backslashes that are not captured. You are downvoting based on mis-reading the question.